# Using Google Cloud Datastore / High Replication Datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, vs-web-application-project

I need help at connecting my server to the Google App Engine.

I created a new Web Application:

```
protected void doGet(HttpRequest req,HttpResponse resp){
   DatastoreService datastore=DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoryService();
   Entity entity = new Entity("Person");
   Entity.setProperty("name",new String("Lucy");
   datastore.put(entity);
```

& deployed it to my AppEngine Project.
If i run it i can see my server running at localhost; and i can see my entitys in the admin-console. But the Entities are stored only locally(, because they don't show up in my App-Engine Projects own EntityView...

Comment: 1. please split your question, there're two questions, it's against StackOverflow rules. 2. it's two absolutelly different things 3. you have to deploy you app to remote server to see data on remote server

Comment: 1.Sorry, I didn't know about that.
2.could you explain me the difference ?
3. I already deployed my eclipse project to my appengine project. Or did i understand you wrong ?

Comment: 2. oh, sorry, i misread your questions. i thought you're asking about difference between Cloud SQL and Cloud Datastore. Cloud Datastore == HRD, same thing, of course. anyway, please split your question

Comment: Ah thanks for that answer! OK i am going to edit my Question.
But it would be nice if you could give me some help with my Appengine.

Comment: How could you possibly invoke `datastore.add()` when the method is supposed to be `datastore.put()`? That code should not compile.

Comment: sry of cause it is datastore.put() like it is in my code,sry.